# how to filter based on Boolean mongodb express js

Tags: mongodb, express, filter

im working on a filter api based on the Answered boolean on schema, and its not working so good for me, i tried this method but it didn't work. its returning all the data without filtering

this is the controller in node

```
  async getAllMessagesbyfilter(account, params) {
    try {
      const messages = await Messages.find({ accountId: account._id }, params);
      return {
        data: messages,
        message: "Messages filterd retrieved successfully",
      };
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  },
```

this is the route handler

```
router.get(
  "/filter",
  authMiddleware,
  async function _listfilter(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const data = await getAllMessagesbyfilter(req.authAccount, req.body);
      return res.status(200).json(data);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  }
);
```

and this is the mongoose schema

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const messagesSchema = new Schema(
  {
    accountId: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
    },
    BotId: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
    },
    Query: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    Answer: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    Answered: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
    ContactId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    ContactUsername: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = model("Messages", messagesSchema);
```

Comment: Not sure what boolean you're referring to. But it looks like the field you're searching on isn't in your schema. Probably need to add it or turn off strict querying

Comment: its Answered on the schema

Comment: None of the code you have shared so far shows a query that is filtering on `Answered` unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: Also there is no accountId field on the schema.

Comment: i have updated the schema, im still learning so i may skipped few things or show me how to do it

Comment: Can you add sample documents and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sending the body of the request as second argument to the find method. It depends on what is in this request body, but if you expect passing something like { Answered: true } to filter the collection based on this property, you're doing it wrong. The second argument is options, such as skip, take, etc. You're most likely looking for something like:

```js
await Messages.find(Object.assign({ accountId: account._id }, params))
```